# How to get specific value in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my JSON tree:

[image]

I want to get the value that is `user_image`.

I try to use this code:

```
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            root.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    base64Image=dataSnapshot.child("Photo").child("user_image").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("base64Image>",base64Image);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

It's no working. How do I get the variable `user_image` value?

Thanks in advance.

I try again , my code change like this:

```
@Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){
                     String image=ds.child("user_image").getValue(String.class);

                        Log.d("image>",image);
                    }
```

The result is that i get all of the user_image.
How do i get the user_image from Mary ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get reference to your object..

```
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Photo/" + photoID);
```

and then add Event listener to `root`

Comment: thanks for your responding , but what is my myUserID ?

Comment: @徐博俊 photoID should be your ID for child in Phot.

Comment: Sorry man , i don't get it , besides there is no .getReference , only root.getRef , can you show me some codes , thanks.

Comment: You are also able to get specific image if you use this

Comment: I am stuck in specific image from Mary , i can get all of the user_image ,but i don't know how to get the Mary's user_image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137976/discussion-between-lalit-jadav-and-).